# Android setting ListView row heights depending on the screen resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/venueImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have an ordinary listview and a custom adapter using the xml above for the row.

I will only have 3 rows, but I want those 3 rows to have equal heights to fit the height of the screen's resolution. At the moment I don't even know how to set the height of the rows because setting the LinearLayout's height doesnt do anything.

Comment: Why use a `ListView` for only 3 rows especially as each row is just an `ImageView`? Just use a single `LinearLayout` (vertical orientation) with 3 `ImageViews` and give each a `layout_weight`. Make the `layout_weight` the same for each `ImageView` and they'll be spaced evenly regardless of screen resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the height of your `ImageView` to get what you want. To set it programmatically, you can do this on the `getView()` of your custom adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View cv = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
            cv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
    }

    ImageView venueImage = (ImageView) cv.findViewById(R.id.venueImage);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vi_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (int)(screenHeight*0.33);
    venueImage.setLayoutParams(vi_params);

    return cv;
}
```

You can get the screen height by adding this code on your main activity:

```
int screenHeight = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Comment: im getting an error when adding that screenHeight variable to my main activity

Comment: I'm guessing that its with the "context". Change the context to "YourActivity.this"